# UnrealBuildTool: ld.lld: error: unable to find library

Tags: linux, linker, linker-errors, unreal-engine4

OS:
Manjaro Linux 4.19.28-1-MANJARO

I have some problem about `ld` in `UnrealBuildTool`. and I'm everything new about all Unreal Stuff.

A week ago, I was found some [Unreal-based Opensource project.](https://github.com/carla-simulator/carla-map-editor) released binary version is working perfectly. But it cannot build on my PC. I think It was gcc linker cannot find `assimp library`.

So I setup environment variable `'LIBRARY_PATH'` and `'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'` However, `UnrealBuildTool` seems not using my local machine's ld linker.

Anyone have idea for this?

### Log

```sh
  [440/442] Compile BuildSettings.cpp
  [441/442] Compile pugixml.cpp
  [442/442] Link (lld) CarlaEditor
  /home/suho/Repository/UnrealEngine/Engine/Extras/ThirdPartyNotUE/SDKs/HostLinux/Linux_x64/v12_clang-6.0.1-centos7/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lassimp
  clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  ERROR: UBT ERROR: Failed to produce item: /home/suho/Workspace/carla-map-editor/Unreal/CarlaEditor/Binaries/Linux/CarlaEditor
         (see /home/suho/Library/Logs/Unreal Engine/LocalBuildLogs/UBT-CarlaEditor-Linux-Development.txt for full exception trace)
  Total build time: 646.23 seconds (Local executor: 0.00 seconds)
Took 646.750887s to run mono, ExitCode=5
ERROR: UnrealBuildTool failed. See log for more details. (/home/suho/Library/Logs/Unreal Engine/LocalBuildLogs/UBT-CarlaEditor-Linux-Development.txt)
       (see /home/suho/Library/Logs/Unreal Engine/LocalBuildLogs/Log.txt for full exception trace)
AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=5 (5)
RunUAT ERROR: AutomationTool was unable to run successfully.
make: *** [Util/BuildTools/Linux.mk:13: package] Error 5
```

full of log are here: https://pastebin.com/HmLphXTe